# Deactivated phone won't connect to wifi

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to transfer my pictures from my old phone and it's deactivated but doesn't give me the option to turn on the wifi. How can I get on wifi?

Comment: what model iPhone, what do you mean deactivated?  Does not no longer have a SIM card in it? If you upgrade to the latest version of IOS you can transfer the photos using AirDrop.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of IOS, or if you can connect to external wifi to upgrade to the latest version of IOS you can transfer the photos via airdrop.

Airdrop utilizes, both wifi and bluetooth.